# asp.net Web Api and mobile aplications

Tags: android, asp.net, xml, rest, asp.net-web-api

I just want to make a TV guide for Android and later some other Mobile Platform. I want to use an RSS updates to update my application. In this specific scenario I want to use http://tvprofil.net/   's RSS resource. I thought that I could just call site's RSS XML from my Android app, parse it, show, and thats the end of the story.

But, my cousine told me that the best way to do things is through Asp.net Web Api Service. Something to deal with REST. So, If I have to change resource, to like some iptv provider's RSS I would just change the Service and not have to deal anything with my mobile application. Other advantage, he said, is if I want to build Windows Phone application or iOS aplication that works the same way, I would have that same service to do job for me and just create UI and basic things for those apps.

The problem is that I have no idea how Asp.net web Api is used.

Can anyone give me some usefull link, or even better, write an example of this thig. I just want the RSS from http://tvprofil.net/ to go through Asp.Net Web Api Service and that I can call service and get it as XML or ... even Json... or to get anything at all to my app.

The whole thing is pretty confusing to me

Answer (score 1):

If a RSS feed has enough data for your application to function then you do not need ASP.NET Web Api. The only role ASP.NET Web Api could play in this scenario is if it acted as an intermediate. E.g. your client application contacts your server application (ASP.NET Web Api) which in turn pulls the data from the actual external data source (tvprofil.net RSS).

For completeness sake, a list of pro's and con's:

***Advantages*** of using an intermediate server

- **Reliability**. You can cache the data of the external data source and serve that data even while the external data source is offline. Also, by caching the data you can lighten the load on the external data source to a bare minimum.
- **Transformability**. Your intermediate server can translate the data of an external data source to another format that is more suitable for your client application. This is useful when you have many external data sources that each serve data in another format. Your intermediate server acts as a layer of abstraction for your client application.

***Disadvantages*** of using an intermediate server

- **More effort**. It will take more effort to develop and host an intermediate server.
- **Reliability**. You must ensure your intermediate server is online and connected to the internet 24/7

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It's been very helpfull. My cousin has a server that will host service. Now I just need to find out how to make it. Any sugsestions?

Comment: Do you have any experience using Visual Studio or .NET? Is the server on a Windows environment? If so, here's a good tutorial on writing your first Web Api: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Yeah, I have a good knowledge of C#, and I know basics of .NET, like Streams, Collections and Files... I'll try that and see

Comment: Very good, with a solid understanding of C# and that tutorial you should be able to create your first Web API. The technology does a lot of the plumbing for you. As the example shows, you can create your first Web API with less than 100 lines of code. Success! :)

Comment: Ok, I have done through this whole tutorial, but as I can see it uses fixed-in data. Working with that is not a problem. Now, It might be that I am very stupid, but I still do not get it how to use it with external resourse like that site's RSS.